# Starting an external application from QML

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to run an external application ( a .exe file ) from a **QML file**? I know that I can use **Qt+QML and QProcess** class but suppose that *I only can access the QML file* and can't recompile the c++/Qt part( Actually this project is a QML+Qt project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't access your C++ code, I'm afraid you can't.

There is an [old open issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-15178) (2010) about this, but it seems it hasn't been considered a lot.

Anyway, it would be really easy if you could add something like [this simple plugin](http://gitorious.org/qml-process-element) to your project (but this would require rebuilding it).